# Inserting complex values to a map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, insert

I am having trouble inserting data into this map.  I honestly can not figure out the way to do this, but the last line of the code I gave is the part that I need fixed.

```
map<string, vector<vector<Obj*>* >* > the_map;
vector<vector<Obj*> *>*  vectors = new vector<vector<Obj*> *>;
vector<Obj*> Obj_vector;
vectors->push_back(&Obj_vector);                                                    
the_map.insert(make_pair(string("field1", &vectors)); //error on this line only
```

Comment: Do you really need that many pointers?

Comment: That's a lot of pointers.  Did you come from Java perchance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 the_map.insert(make_pair(string("field1"),  vectors)); 
                       //you forgot this ^  ^
                       //                   |
                       //                   & is not needed here
```

By the way, I suspect the usage of so many pointers in your code, and especially these two lines:

```
vector<Obj*> Obj_vector;  //this is local variable
vectors->push_back(&Obj_vector); //inserting address of the local variable
```

Inserting *address* of a local variable into vector?

**Beware** that the local variable wouldn't exist after it goes out of scope, which in turn, means that the address which you just inserted into the vector, points to the destroyed object, and using it would invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: ahh, I got it finally, thanks so much!  And i will look into the local variable issue

Comment: @StephenD: Good. Must look into the local variable issues.